# Can I make the SharePoint form interactive?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-2016

I have a custom list where the value in the first column determines which other columns should have value. Or rather, the record type(as selected in the first column) defines what all data I should collect in the form.

I want to continue using the default/designer form for the list.

Is it possible to manipulate the form fields using JavaScript after identifying the value selected in the first column?

EDIT: When I create a new form, I am able to add javascript, and show/hide fields.
However, I can't figure out how to read the fields in javascript.

Comment: Trying to read this there was some confusion on what exactly you want to do. Do you have pictures showing what your trying to do, I believe I can better help.

From the sounds of it, you want to use JS to create a form? If this is the case I can help you through that but I need more detail.

Comment: @bigchungus I have a form that is very much in use. I am trying to read the selected value in a checkbox list and then show the following fields based on the selection.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way is to use jQuery. You just have to refer jQuery in your form then you can fetch the field from title or name attribute whichever is applicable.

```
$("input[title='title_of_the_field']").val()
```

Comment: This is working for a text field; how can I do it for a checkbox list? I am not able to see the Title attribute or anything.